# Set values in row to zero before index value of row [NumPy or Tensorflow]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I have an array `A` with shape (N,). I am taking N=5 for illustration:

```
A = np.array([0,1,1,0,1])
```

And I want to transform it to the following NxN matrix `B`. Solutions in both NumPy and Tensorflow are good but the latter is preferred.

```
B = np.array([[0,1,1,0,1],
              [0,1,1,0,1],
              [0,1,1,0,1],
              [0,0,0,0,1],
              [0,0,0,0,1]])
```

One solution can be comprised of following steps:

1. Repeat array `A` N times
2. Loop through each row `i`. Look for the index of the last zero until the `i-th` element of that row.
3. Replace all elements preceding that index with zeros.

Another illustration with N=10:

```
D = np.array([0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0])
```

```
E = np.array([[0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0],
              [0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0],
              [0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0],
              [0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
```

Comment: Why would the fifth row of B be [0,0,0,0,1] if the 5th element is a 1. And what is the idea behind C?

Comment: For B) it's because the fifth element of A is 1. 5th row and 5th element of B is thus a 1, so it stays like that. I only need to modify before the ith element if the value is a zero.

C) is just an incremental version. Both can be a solution for my problem

Comment: Need more explanation

Comment: I made it simpler (without matrix C) and added more explanation. Hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: Can you explain, why the last row of matrix B is not `[0,1,1,0,1]`?

Comment: My earlier description was faulty - sorry. I modified the description of the steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = np.array([0,1,1,0,1])
N = A.shape[0]
column = (A > 0).reshape((N, 1))
mask = np.ones((N, N), dtype=np.bool)
mask = np.where(column, False, np.tril(mask, -1))
mask = np.cumsum(mask, axis=0)
B = np.where(mask, 0, np.tile(A, (N, 1)))
```

```
[[0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1]]
```

#### Explanation

1. Compute lower triangular matrix

```
[[False False False False False]
 [ True False False False False]
 [ True  True False False False]
 [ True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True  True  True False]]
```

2. Find ones in A and fill corresponding rows with False

```
[[False False False False False]
 [False False False False False]
 [False False False False False]
 [ True  True  True False False]
 [False False False False False]]
```

3. Compute cumulative sum to set zeros to all rows below. This is a mask of all elements that should be zeroed out

```
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0]]
```

4. Repeat array A N times

```
[[0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1]]
```

5. Mask its elements

```
[[0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 1 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

@rafiko1 your explanation is still not clear to me. But try the following.

```
import numpy as np

nn = 5
A = np.array([0,1,1,0,1])
#A = np.array([0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0])

#  we create the matrix B and set required entries to zero
B = np.repeat(A.reshape(1,nn),nn,axis=0)

# test condition:
# test if the ith element in the ith row is zero
# this is accomplished using np.diag
boolarr = np.diag(B==0)
# this gives us the row index in B where the condition is true
idx_b_rows = np.where(boolarr == True)

# get indices of entries before diagonal
idx_lower_rows,idx_lower_cols = np.tril_indices(nn,k=-1)

# get the indices of the entries of idx_b_rows in idx_lower_rows
idx = np.where(np.in1d(idx_lower_rows,idx_b_rows))[0]

# set the entries before the diagonal to zero
B[idx_lower_rows[idx],idx_lower_cols[idx]] = 0

print(B)
```